# Do you know how to init ov7670?

Tags: microcontroller, camera

Do you know how to initialise this [ov7670](http://www.trulydisplays.com/ccm/specs/0.3M%20Sensor%20OV7670.pdf) camera?

[image: ov7670 camera module]

[image]

Comment: No I don't, but I don't see how that is relevant.

Comment: @RickAnt - Have you read the datasheet? If so, is there something about it which you don't understand ?

Comment: Initialise using what? A FPGA, micro controller, in what language Verilog, HDL, C, Assembly? At the moment its very vague and might be closed.

Comment: Given that : 1. The query is clearly about how to design with a given IC. 2. The provided datasheet did not have complete information. 3. Information was available and was liable to be of value and interest to others ||| It does not seem that a number of he comments made were constructive or sensible. || Elitist, maybe.

Comment: using microcontroller with C

Comment: @RussellMcMahon  +1 to your comment.  +1 to your answer.  But we've got a difficult case here.  On one hand, it's a good topic.  Working with Omnivision cameras is tough.  One need any help he can get.  On the other hand, the conversation took a turn towards "do u has teh codes".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the information in the basic data sheet there is information provided in their document "**Serial Camera Control Bus functional specification**"

Here -  [Omnivision Technologies - Serial Camera Control Bus - SCCB](http://www.fer.unizg.hr/_download/repository/ov-sccb%5B1%5D.pdf) functional specification

Here is a two page product brief for your module. Useful in that it shows an envisaged application. VGA x 30 fps capable. [OV7670 vga Product Brief](http://www.datasheetarchive.com/omnivision%2a%20Sccb-datasheet.html#) .
 Some text from this product brief at end of this post.

While the capabilities of this module are well surpassed by modern camera phone IC's the 30 fps x VGA rate could still be of substantial value in many applications.

[Omni Vision sensors product page](http://www.ovt.com/products/) - links to all sensor pages, including ...

[VGA Sensors page](http://www.ovt.com/products/category.php?id=15)

Also [Application notes](http://www.ovt.com/applications/)

---

These appear to be for related sensor ICs but may be of some use

[OV9740 sensor - 720p](http://www.ovt.com/products/sensor.php?id=97)

[OV10630 sensor - 720p](http://www.ovt.com/products/sensor.php?id=87)

[Data sheet for their 9655 camera](http://www.surveyor.com/blackfin/OV9655-datasheet.pdf)

---

**From OV7670 product brief.**

Based on a 3.6 μmpixel architecture, the OV7670
enables ultra-thin cameramodules of just 6 x 6 x 4.1mm.
This is a critical characteristic for slim camera phones
and notebook applications since the camera modules can
be no thicker than the LCD housing.
Also important in enabling such thin modules is that the
OV7670 allows module designs to move to a 2-plastic
lens design. Additionally, the OV7670's unique non-linear
micro lens shift technology allows for a reduction in the
distance between sensor and lens, shrinking the module
even further without loss of image quality or camera
performance.

The OV7670 employs OmniVision's proprietary
OmniPixel® architecture, which significantly increases
signal-to-noise ratio and delivers exceptional low-light
performance. Operating at a low voltage, the OV7670
image sensor provides the full functionality of a single
chip VGA camera and image processor in a small
footprint package. This includes full-frame, sub-sampled
or windowed 8-bit images in a wide range of formats
controlled through a serial camera control bus (SCCB)
interface.

The OV7670 can operate at 30 frames per second (fps)
in VGA with full user control over image quality,
formatting and output data transfer. As part of
OmniVision's next generation of image sensors, the
OV7670 delivers low-noise, low-cost, low-power
consumption, high integration, wide dynamic range and
excellent low-light performance.
Find outmore at www.ovt.com.

Comment: how about using AL422 FIFO, still the same code for init ?